# Spotfire - Graphical Table - Icons appearance based on some condition

Tags: spotfire

I tried  to use the Graphical table to show an icon in “RBG” color based on some conditions.  In the screenshot1 (attached below) if the value shown in column 2 is less than 5, I want to show the icon next to it in RED otherwise in GREEN. But only one color icon is appearing. The reason is an ‘aggregation’ of data is automatically selected for the variable  ‘FPDueDateDifference’  used in the condition (Please see screenshot 2 attached below. The ‘count’ aggregation is chosen by default.) .  There is no “none” option available to choose and avoid the aggregation of data. Only if the aggregation is not chosen, i could add the custom expression "if [FPDueDateDifference] < 5, "RED","GREEN")". Based on the return value i would add the rules to display the icons in appropriate colour.

Please suggest some way to avoid this situation.

**Screenshot 1:**
[Screenshot1 shows the column 2 values and icon next to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m6NE.png)
**Screenshot 2**
[shows the "count" aggregator is selected and "None" option not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aACC2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have an aggregation. A Graphical Table is similar to a Cross Table so you have categories, and the the aggregated values associated with these categories. You can still apply your logic though. After you set your value to `count([FPDueDateDifference])` or if it suits you to use `max()` or `first()` what ever other aggregation, click "Add Rule" and then set up your logic like the below:

[image: Greater Than]

Then add another rule for Less Than or Equal To.

Comment: did you try `MAX()` or `FIRST()` this should work for your case since your values are unique

Comment: Thanks SCSimon for your answer. Yes i understand i must have an aggregation. The error i made was, i chose a wrong aggregation. so the icons were shown in one color. Actually after understanding your answer, i found how silly my question was. Thanks for sparing your time to solve questions on this portal. Appreciate your effort and time. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your comments @pradeep. We are happy to help those who are like you. Thanks for your question.